# How create glossy button in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, graphics, gdi+

I want create glossy buttons with GDI+ or Silverlight with C#, any ideas or trickery how to create a glossy button? Somethings like images below:

I am interesting more in GDI+ solutions.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZguQG.jpg]

Comment: They are just images, created in Photoshop and the like.

Comment: @hashi Dave Crawford (an ex colleague of mine who now works at Microsoft) has some examples just like this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dave/archive/2008/10/06/dave-s-glossy-controls-for-silverlight-2-released.aspx

Comment: @Marc Garvell Do you mean this blog ? (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dave/)

Comment: @hashi Review this article please.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/expression/ExpressionBlendButtons.aspx

Comment: @shaahin yes, I already edited it in, but thanks for looking

Comment: You can use buttons from this article: [Enhanced GlassButton using GDI+](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/buttons/Enhanced_GlassButton.aspx)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- [Creating Gel Buttons with Windows Forms : Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2006/02/23/538164.aspx) *([archive](http://archive.is/WXD8l))*
- [Creating Gel Buttons with Windows Forms : Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2006/03/01/541384.aspx) *([archive](http://archive.is/Z5Daq))*
- [Creating Gel Buttons with Windows Forms : Part 3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2006/03/08/546259.aspx) *([archive](http://archive.is/rOhBa))*

Chris Jackson, Microsoft Appcompat Guy, wrote that for .NET (i.e. C# and GDI+).

[image]
*Windows Forms Gel Buttons : First Revision*

[image]
*Windows Forms Gel Buttons : Second Revision*

[image]
*Windows Forms Gel Buttons - Third Revision*

All the code is there, along with careful consideration of

- scaling with high dpi
- performance and bitmap caching

Comment: cool I never saw it you should get the right answer :)

Answer (score 12):

[Example here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/WindowsVistaRenderer.aspx):

> This article demonstrates how to use the `WindowsVistaRenderer` and how it was created...
>
> I've found different layers on the button drawing...
>
> A glossy effect is drawn on the north of the button. The green color represents an almost transparent color...
>
> Now, the order in which we draw these layers is critical. That order is:
>
> 1. Outer border
> 2. Button background color (if button is checked)
> 3. Glossy effect
> 4. Border
> 5. Button fill glossy emphasis
> 6. Inner border
> 7. Glow
> 8. Text and image of the button...

Comment: thanks , Its good link but I am looking for more professional tutorials or samples (Better if be GDI+)

Comment: Thanks Guys first time I got 6 thumbs :)

Comment: That is a good article, but really alot of the fancy graphics in Vista are pre-made bitmaps according to a MSFT source and is also much less time consuming to create a good UI with a premade bitmap in say Photoshop then it is to re-invent the wheel in program code.

Answer (score 3):

In Silverlight it's very simple to create this buttons in Xaml with brushes.
See this link for some good samples: [Glossy Brushes using Radial Gradient Brush in WPF](http://learnwpf.com/post/2008/01/31/Glossy-Brushes-using-Radial-Gradient-Brush-in-WPF.aspx)

You can also use *Microsoft Expression Design* to create these buttons or simply import from *Adobe Illustrator* or *Adobe Photoshop* and then export them to Xaml.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check this CodeProject article, a nice tutorial shows how to make some glossy circular buttons in expression blend: [Glass Orb Button in Silverlight](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SilverlightGlassOrbButton.aspx)

Also there are lots of projects related to glass buttons and glossy effects made using GDI+ or expression blend in codeproject.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Expression Blend.

Comment: Yep ,  He can also . but I think its better to describing more.